# loading a local JSON file with d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I know JSON can't load locally in `Chrome` as many other questions have discussed.  I am trying to recreate this: https://romsson.github.io/dragit/example/nations.html

I have tried to implement the solution of hardcoding the json.

Working code:

```
d3.json("https://rawgit.com/romsson/dragit/master/data/nations.json", function(nations) {
```

....

My attempt to load `nations.json` locally:

```
var nations = [{"name":"Angola","region":"Sub-Saharan Africa","income":[[2006,12127071],[2007,12420476],[2008,12707546]],
"lifeExpectancy":[[2006,46.02],[2007,46.54],[2008,47.06]]},
{"name":"Benin","region":"Sub-Saharan Africa","income":[[2006,7862944],[2007,8078314],[2008,8294941]],
"lifeExpectancy":[[2006,60.6],[2007,61.03],[2008,61.47]]}]

d3.json(nations, function(nations) {

....
```

I get the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: `d3.json()` takes a URL, not an object.

Comment: just change d3.json(nations,...) content to a function and pass nations object.

Comment: @karthick that just becomes `function(nations) {`? I'm very new to javascript and d3, but that fails to work as well

Comment: yes. it should be like that. Because d3.json is used to load data from url not an object present in the page. So if you have an object already in the page just pass it to the required function. function draw(nationsObj){...}   draw(nations);

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Please submit as answer if you want some credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3.json is used to load data from url not an object present in the page.  So if you have an object already in the page just pass it to the required function.

Example

```
function draw(nationsObj){
    // A bisector since many nation's data is sparsely-defined.
       var bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d[0]; });

        .....contents
} 

draw(nations);
```